# How do I initialise static variables in javascript static class?

Tags: javascript

I have a static class in javascript...

```
var Logger = {
    logtofirefox: function (str, priority) {

         console.log(str);        

    },
    logtoie: function (str, priority) {

         alert(str);        

    }

}
```

I call it like this from another file...

```
Logger.log('Hello World');
```

But I want to inject the string 'log : ' before the words 'Hello World' on all functions.

Wondering if this is possible with minimum fuss?

Comment: From the given Logger object I'd say the call `Logger.log('Hello World');` would throw a TypeError: *Object #<Object> has no method 'log'*

Answer (score 1):

Just update the output for each function :

```
var Logger = {
    logtofirefox: function (str, priority) {
         console.log('log : ' + str);        
    },
    logtoie: function (str, priority) {
         alert('log : ' + str);        
    }
};
```

Comment: This isnt really what I was looking for. You are duplicating code, what if I have multiple statements I have to then maintain multiple strings. I want to be able to do it all from one place. One static string....

Comment: what calls each function ? `logtofirefox` / `logtoie` ? you could prepend the 'log' string there ?